# ModernCV Remove horizontal line in sections

Tags: moderncv

I want to write my cv with `moderncv-Classic` style. Can you tell me, how I can remove the horizontal line in the left of each section?

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \strut\sectionstyle{#2\hfill}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading
  }
```

The above code is the core of what is required. Now time for an MWE:
**The MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \strut\sectionstyle{#2\hfill}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading
  }

\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{sm}{
  \strut\subsectionstyle{#2}{\color{color1}{\subsectionfill}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{0.5ex}\@afterheading}
%
\makeatother

\name{SUBHAM}{SONI}
\address{ABC}{XYZ}{PQR}
\phone[mobile]{1234567}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{CAREER OBJECTIVE}
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can you pls me, where I have to put in the first Codex? The ModernCV file or the style file?

Comment: The first code must be put after your `\usepackage`s commands , it has to begin with `\makeatletter` , then the code , followed by `\makeatother`. Then, your commands for the title like `\name` etc, then `\begin{document}` and `end{document}`. See the MWE for reference.@Aline

Answer (score 3):

It largely depends on the style you are using (and on the version of `moderncv`) which is the reason why a MWE would be good.

Assuming you are using the latest version of moderncv and the `classic` or `casual` theme you can put

```
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0ex}}}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother
```

in your preamble (before `\begin{document}`) to get sections with an invisible bar or

```
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  {\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother
```

for removing the bar completely.