# How to get rid of horizontal line in moderncv?

Tags: formatting, packages, templates, moderncv

In the beginning of each section in the `moderncv` package there is a horizontal line. I cannot figure out where to find the code to modify/ get rid of it.

e.g. https://de.overleaf.com/articles/asma-turkis-curriculum-vitae/trfmznnxpkfm

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180131/134144 could be helpful.